# How to add a firewall exception to a remote server in C#

Tags: c#

The following is the method I wrote, but after execution, the corresponding firewall exception cannot be added to the remote server.

```
private void AddFirewallException(string remoteServerAddress)
{
    try
    {
        // 创建 PowerShell 脚本内容
        string psScript = $@"
            $remoteServerAddress = '{remoteServerAddress}'
            $command = 'netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=MyFirewallRule dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=1433 remoteip=$remoteServerAddress'
            Invoke-Expression -Command $command
        ";

        // 创建 PowerShell 进程
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = "powershell.exe";
        psi.Arguments = $"-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command \"{psScript}\"";
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

        // 启动 PowerShell 进程并等待执行完成
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = psi;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();

        // 检查 PowerShell 执行结果
        if (process.ExitCode == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("防火墙例外添加成功！");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("防火墙例外添加失败！");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"添加防火墙例外时出现错误：{ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

I tried to use the powershell command and the cmd command, but there was no way to add it successfully, and they were all run by an administrator.